# How to find the closure of the following set?

Tags: analysis

How to find the closure in $l^{\infty}$ of the set

$$M =\{(a_1,a_2,..........) : \textrm{all but finitely many } a_i=0\}?$$

Comment: De donde eres Andres?

Comment: Google Translate: "Where are you Andres?" :) Don't worry everyone, I've got this

Comment: Also, that seems to be a personal question...

Comment: I don't get the joke...

Comment: Congratulations to the translation team--nice cooperative effort. Now, to answer it ;)

Comment: @Nameless "Estaban hablando en español, así que estaba traduciendo para todos."

Answer (score 1):

Estoy pensando que "cerradura" es el "closure" del conjunto. Si este es el caso, creo que la respuesta es $\{x = (a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots): \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0\}$. Considera $x_n \in M$ and $x_n \rightarrow x= (a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots)$ en $\| \cdot \|_\infty$

Prove it by showing that any sequence in the closure converges to zero and that any sequence that converges to zero is in the closure.

The key is that if $x$ is in the closure, then there exists a sequence $x_n$ in $M$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \|x-x_n\| = 0$

Comment: "I'm thinking that "lock" is the "closure" of the set. If this is the case, I think the answer is..." the mad translator strikes again